# Why does OSX and Windows import my .pfx file differently?

Tags: windows, macos, ssl-certificate

I've got a .pfx file I can't share (work-related), but when I load it up on Windows my public key starts with `30 82 01 0a ... (truncated, see screenshot)`

[Windows screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HwuV.png)

And when I load it up with on macOS it begins with `BF:CF:10...`

[macOS screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpTGF.png)

Even though it is the same file, the serial number of the loaded certificate and the public key seem to differ, which is causing problems for my C# Unity project when I try to connect to it. They have the same Authority Key Identifier, Subject Key Identifier, and Thumbprint, but differ in their Serial Number (`4274337a15ab78c4` for Windows, and `4788598903244265668` and public key).

Is there a reason why Windows and macOS would differ in the details when loading the **same** certificate file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they are importing it the same, just displaying it differently. The difference in serial numbers is due to Windows showing it in hex, and macOS in decimal.

The public key is a bit more complicated, but look closely at the top line of the Windows display. It starts with "30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01 00", but the bytes following that, "bf cf 10 be e7 b1 1d af ..." match with the first bytes of what macOS lists as the public key.

I don't have a Windows system to look at, but I think what's happening is that the "Public Key" it shows is actually an [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1) data structure *containing* the modulus and exponent that make up the public key. macOS, on the other hand, lists the modulus (labeled "Public Key") and exponent separately, and doesn't bother with the surrounding ASN.1 headers (the "30 82 ..." stuff).